# failed to start my android activity, javanullpiontException occured

Tags: android

```
public class BouncingBallActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View bouncingBallView = new BouncingBallView(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(bouncingBallView);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your logcat error.

Comment: post BouncingBallView Class it must be extends View

Answer (score 1):

Please note:

1. Make sure all your activities are listed in the `manifest` file
2. Make sure BouncingBallView class has a constructor of the type public

BouncingBallView(Context context)

{
    super(context);

}

1. `BouncingBallView` must extend `View`
2. check all your code. check whether you are returning null anywhere.
3. Post your logcat trace and and try and pin point where exactly are you going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
View bouncingBallView = new BouncingBallView(this);
```

put this line after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`